# Log in script shows blank page

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, logout

This code does not seem to be working. It only shows a blank page when I click the login button. What could be the issue.

```
<?php
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("register", $con);

$query =("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '". $username ."' AND password = '". $password ."'     LIMIT 1");

$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($count == 0) {
  echo 'Error: username or password wrong ';
} else {
  echo "Registration Successful, redirecting";

header("refresh:3; url=login.html");
mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', '1');
` on the top of your page and see what you get

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: How about you debug your code?

Comment: @user4258493 Please accept the answer if it solved your error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an IDE not only an Editor!
Using my IDE it showed me an error right away and it was quite easy to fix afterwards:

```
<?php
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("register", $con);

$query =("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '". $username ."' AND password = '". $password ."'     LIMIT 1");

$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($count == 0) {
  echo 'Error: username or password wrong ';
} else {
  echo "Registration Successful, redirecting";

}

header("refresh:3; url=login.html");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

You forgot the closing curly brackets of the else part AND the semi colon in your second last line!

Comment: Amazing. People take the effort to make an account, make a question only to have something so simple be the issue.

Comment: I don't know. But when you start developing {ProgrammingLanugage} and only use an editor and basically don't know anything about {ProgrammingLanugage} then you might get lost and try to get other people to figure out your mistakes instead of reading a good tutorial that tells you to use an IDE.

Comment: So? To ghet that right is actually what other people pay YOU for and not us!

Comment: AND your initial question thereby is solved. So please accept the answer and add a new question if you need more help.